# DBT Macros to perform computations

Tags: macros, dbt

i was trying to write a macros which would be capable of doing various computations and return the final result.

Does macros accept only Block level codes like if or for loops? and not set of individual statements?

please help me with this

Thanks

Comment: SQL doesn't support macros so I've removed the tag.

Comment: Could you add a bit more context as to what you would like your macro to do?

Comment: Hi Dylan, PLease have a look at this code
`code
{% macro sum_items(column_1,column_2) %}
    ({{ column_1}}+{{column_1 }})
{% endmacro %}
code`

does macros support multi line coding? i tried adding multiple lines to it , not neccesarily related but it was throwing an error in the  model after compiling
as the resultant query generated was not syntactically correct

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks i was not sure of it.as i was using dbt macros along with SQL

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide some examples of what you're trying to achieve, and maybe what you've already tried? As it is, it's too vague to provide a specific answer. Maybe also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for some general advice on asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot you can do with macros. Most native python operations are possible, albeit in a clunky non-pythonic way (no list comprehensions here).

For example, one can call any method of a python builtin data type:

```
{% set my_base_models = [] %}

{% for i in graph.nodes.values() %}

   {% if i["name"].startswith('base_model') %}
       
        {% do my_list.append(i) %}

    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Key points:

1. call `{% do <obj>.<method>() %}` with any state-altering method (eg. `pop()` , `append()`, etc) to execute it
2. Put results into variables with `{% set <var> = <expression> %}`
3. Check out out [filters and tests](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/) in standard jinja to filter and test mappings (dicts) and lists
4. Check out the list of dbt specific [jinja context variables](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions) and methods